# pipeline works but bash script doesn't

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, awk

I'm converting groups of 4 lines into one-liners, and then sorting them by the 2nd column. The following works fine with pipes, but when I turn it into a 2-line bash script, the second line doesn't compute. It's fine as it is with pipes, but it would help if someone could point out what I am doing wrong with my bash script, for future reference.

The command line (works fine):

```
cat test.txt | awk '{ printf("%s",$0); n++; if(n%4==0) { printf("\n");} else { printf("\t");} }' | sort -t $'\t' -k2,2 > testout.txt
```

The bash script (awk seems to run but not sort):

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{ printf("%s",$0); n++; if(n%4==0) { printf("\n");} else { printf("\t");} }'
sort -t $'\t' -k2,2
```

Input test.txt:

```
@1:1:9834:8392:Y
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT
+1:1:9834:8392:Y
IIHIIIIGGGIIIIDDDIIIIFFFHIGEFEFEFEFE
@1:1:1323:1032:Y
AGCAGCATTGTACAGGGCTATCATGGAATTCTCGGG
+1:1:1323:1032:Y
HHHBHHBHBHGBGGGH8HHHGGGGFHBHHHHBHHHH
@1:1:1610:1033:Y
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+1:1:1610:1033:Y
HHEHHHHHHHHHHHBGGD>GGD@G8GGGGDHBHH4C
@1:1:1679:1032:Y
CGGTGGATCACTCGGCTCGTGCGTCGATGAAGAACG
+1:1:1679:1032:Y
IIIHIIGIIIIIIIDIIIFHEIEDGFEFGECEEEGB
```

output testout.txt (desired output):

```
@1:1:1610:1033:Y    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    +1:1:1610:1033:Y    HHEHHHHHHHHHHHBGGD>GGD@G8GGGGDHBHH4C
@1:1:9834:8392:Y    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT    +1:1:9834:8392:Y    IIHIIIIGGGIIIIDDDIIIIFFFHIGEFEFEFEFE
@1:1:1323:1032:Y    AGCAGCATTGTACAGGGCTATCATGGAATTCTCGGG    +1:1:1323:1032:Y    HHHBHHBHBHGBGGGH8HHHGGGGFHBHHHHBHHHH
@1:1:1679:1032:Y    CGGTGGATCACTCGGCTCGTGCGTCGATGAAGAACG    +1:1:1679:1032:Y    IIIHIIGIIIIIIIDIIIFHEIEDGFEFGECEEEGB
```

The bash script usage:

```
cat test.txt | ./duplicates_1000.sh > testout.txt
```

The output of bash script (awk is executed but not sort):

```
@1:1:9834:8392:Y    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT    +1:1:9834:8392:Y    IIHIIIIGGGIIIIDDDIIIIFFFHIGEFEFEFEFE
@1:1:1323:1032:Y    AGCAGCATTGTACAGGGCTATCATGGAATTCTCGGG    +1:1:1323:1032:Y    HHHBHHBHBHGBGGGH8HHHGGGGFHBHHHHBHHHH
@1:1:1610:1033:Y    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    +1:1:1610:1033:Y    HHEHHHHHHHHHHHBGGD>GGD@G8GGGGDHBHH4C
@1:1:1679:1032:Y    CGGTGGATCACTCGGCTCGTGCGTCGATGAAGAACG    +1:1:1679:1032:Y    IIIHIIGIIIIIIIDIIIFHEIEDGFEFGECEEEGB
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pipe the output of `awk` to `sort`

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{ printf("%s",$0); n++; if(n%4==0) { printf("\n");} else { printf("\t");} }' | sort -t $'\t' -k2,2
```

Or they run sequential, `awk` will eat all inputs, and nothing left for `sort`

Comment: Ah, shouldn't I add `| cat` at the end? Otherwise it won't print anything :)

Comment: use `sort -t "[TAB]" -k2,2` where [TAB] is you hitting tab on the keyboard

Comment: It's working for me... I added `| cat` at the end of your solution and it is working just fine. If you edit your solution I will accept it as the answer :)

Comment: `| cat` is totally useless, can you try without it ?

Comment: I did without it, and it doesn't output anything.